# Updating a Delimited String Value in MySQL

Tags: mysql

Let's say I have a column value of `'1|2|3|4|5'`. These values are a string representation of an array, and I'd like to remove a single value in the string (by integer) resulting in `'1|2|4|5'`. What is the most efficient way in MySQL to do that given that the integer to be removed could be anywhere in the string?

Comment: The most efficient way is to normalize your database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something like this:

```
UPDATE yourtable
SET col = TRIM(BOTH '|' FROM REPLACE(
            REPLACE(
              CONCAT('|',REPLACE(col, '|', '||'), '|'),
              '|3|', '')
            , '||', '|')
          )
```

Here I double every `|` to `||`, I then add a `|` at the beginning and one at the end. This way, every element has its own `|` at the start and `|` at the end.

Now we can safely replace `|3|` with an empty string.

We now need to convert double `||` back to `|`, and trim the string to eventually remove the `|` at the beginning and the one at the end.

See it working [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ff0ea0/1).

If you are sure that element 3 cannot be present more than once, you can skip doubling `|` to `||`, and you have to replace `|3|` with `|`. The rest is the same.

Comment: +1 for creativity. However, I suspect there must be a cleaner way to do this with REGEX?????.

Comment: @DeweyOx thanks :) a regex substitution would be much more cleaner, but mysql supports only a subset of regexp functions natively, you have to install this udf to have a full regex support: http://www.mysqludf.org/lib_mysqludf_preg/

Comment: Thanks @fthiella. Will use this until I miraculously find a cleaner alternative.

Answer (score 0):

```
update table set col=replace ( col, '3','')
```

This will do a case sensitive search on the column. If its a huge table,  have an index on this column. Results will be reasonably fast.

Comment: What if there's a value of `33` in there?

Comment: This results in a double delimiter - '1|2||4|5'. I'm looking for a way to 'split' the value, remove one from the resultant 'array', and them 'join' the results back with the delimiter.